# Inter-Country Civil Partnership Recognized?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

As a follow-up to my question a couple of days ago on which visa I needed to move to Scotland, I've completed my visa application providing for a civil union within 3 months of my arrival.  However, in the application there was absolutely no mention of the fact that civil unions, at least in the UK, are only for same-sex couples.  (Sorry, Martin Bonner, I didn't listen to what you said because I'd done so much research and never seen a thing about this.)  So my quandary is this: if John and I go to another country for a civil union, will UK immigration accept it?  And will I even be allowed to leave Scotland to have the civil union performed within my first three months there?

It's Friday afternoon.  I've called the attorneys in my family, our solicitors in Scotland, and don't know where else to try.  I have an appointment Monday to get my bio-metric card.  If all else fails, I'll cancel that and get a refund on my visa app.  I fly out Oct. 1 - hope that happens.

Comment: Did you see the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_partnership_in_the_United_Kingdom in a comment on your previous question by @phoog? I am not an expert but I would say that if you change your plans and don’t enter into a civil partnership during your upcoming stay in the U.K. the visa you’ve just applied for wouldn't be valid so, while leaving wouldn’t be a problem, you would not be allowed to re-enter the UK. You need advice from an Immigration lawyer. You should also be aware that Scottish and English law can differ http://www2.gov.scot/Topics/Justice/law/17867/18313/faq-general

Comment: Also https://www.gov.scot/publications/future-civil-partnership-scotland-analysis-consultation-responses/

Comment: Martin Bonner was wrong.  Civil unions were recently made available to opposite sex couples.

Comment: @phoog The Bill to change the law is still awaiting Royal Assent and will not come into force before 31 Dec 2019 https://rutterslaw.co.uk/2019/03/19/can-heterosexual-couples-enter-into-a-civil-partnership/

Comment: @Cindy This may be too personal a question, but why are you choosing a civil partnership over marriage? There are some differences https://www.slatergordon.co.uk/media-centre/blog/2016/01/what-are-the-differences-between-marriage-and-civil-partnership/

Comment: @Traveller I see.  The Wikipedia article seems somewhat misleading in that case, at least for those of us not fully familiar with the steps required to give effect to enacted legislation.

Comment: Thank you to all for your input.  Civil unions for heterosexual couples are NOT legal yet in the UK.  I looked into countries where it is, but there was still the question of whether I'd be allowed back in.  So we're probably going to marry.  We're both in our mid-60's and divorced; civil union seemed less complicated.  My visa application works for both civil unions and weddings within the first few months.  There's still a snag because my quest for an e-mail response from a registrar has yielded nothing yet, so I may have no proof we're going to get married.  Unsure what else I can try.

Comment: @Cindy In the UK civil partnerships are no more or less complicated than marriages. For a simple marriage, you can just do it at the register office, with both of you, the registrar and two witnesses. This identical to the procedure for a civil partnership. So even if it were possible, it wouldn't be any easier.

Comment: Thanks, M.Jeffryes.  We're a go on the wedding, and I have e-mails from the registrar in Scotland to prove it, as much as we can at this point.  And we're both  happy about our decision.